# grep one pattern over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I'm trying to figure out a way for me to use `grepl()` of only one partial pattern over multiple columns with `mutate()`. I want to have a new column that will be TRUE or FALSE if ANY of a set of columns contains a certain string.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A1.1234567_10", "A1.1234567_20"), 
                 var1 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var2 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var3 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var4 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var5 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var6 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var7 = c("NORMAL", "ABNORMAL"), 
                 var8 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL")), 
            .Names = c("ID", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

            ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8
1 A1.1234567_10 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL
2 A1.1234567_20 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL
```

I tried

```
df$abnormal %>% mutate( abnormal = ifelse(grepl("abnormal",df[,119:131]) , TRUE, FALSE)))
```

and about 100 other things. I want the final format to be

```
             ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8    abnormal
1 A1.1234567_10 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL FALSE
2 A1.1234567_20 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL TRUE
```

Whenever I try I get false every time

Comment: A few questions - first, you seem to be inconsistent in your example data which has "ABNORMAL", but your code checks for "SUSPECTED". Second, do you really need `grepl` - by which I mean do you need to *search within a string for a pattern*, or would equality checking work? Equality checking would be much easier and more efficient, but it will only work for an exact match, i.e. "this subject is ABNORMAL" would require `grepl` to match.

Comment: But if you can just check for equality, you could do `df$abnormal = rowSums(select(df, starts_with("var")) == "ABNORMAL") > 0`. (Or with `mutate` if you prefer).

Comment: @Gregor  Hi i edited it to say abnormal. The real dataframe will contain something like "Suspected_13" or "Suspected_15" or "Suspected_18" so I really need to pick out the string "Suspected"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do this:

```
temp = sapply(your_data[columns_you_want_to_check],
              function(x) grepl("suspected", x, ingore.case = TRUE))
your_data$abnormal = rowSums(temp) > 0
```

I just used `your_data` since your question switches between `df` and `test.file`.

If you really want to use `mutate`, you could do

```
df %>%
mutate(abnormal = rowSums(
  sapply(select(., starts_with("var")),
         function(x) grepl("suspected", x, ingore.case = TRUE)
  )) > 0
)
```

If you need more efficiency, you can use `fixed = TRUE` instead of `ignore.case = TRUE` if you can count on the case being consistent. (Maybe convert everything `to_lower()` first.)

Leave off the `> 0` to get the count for each row.

Comment: i used your mutate suggestion. this actually came out with a different output than i wanted but it ended up working a lot better because the column has the number of times the string appeared. my next step was going to be looking for rows that have multiple "suspected" calls. Thanks so much

Comment: Sounds like you missed the `> 0` bit at the end (or maybe I'm missing a parenthesis), but I'm glad that's what you wanted.