# grep from different columns in r

Tags: r

I have a very simple question but I don't know how to get the desired result.

I have a data.frame with several columns and I want to grep a value across four of them to get a subset of the data.frame.

Here is a dummy example

```
>df1
V1  V2           V3           V4           V5
 a  abc|ccc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  yyy|lmn|trs  abc|ggt|hgy
 b  atc|cjc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  abc|lmn|trs  abc|opq|sss
 c  auc|chc|ggg  abc|ccc|shg  gtc|lmn|trs  hyt|lki|ddd
 d  aoc|cfc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  yyy|lmn|trs  rmn|wde|tre
```

I would like to subset the data.frame based on `abc` pattern for the columns `V2,V3,V4,V5`

I know that for one column I can do

```
 df2 <- df[grep('abc`, df$V1),]
```

But how to get this result using multiple columns?

```
>df2
V1  V2           V3           V4           V5
 a  abc|ccc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  yyy|lmn|trs  abc|ggt|hgy
 b  atc|cjc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  abc|lmn|trs  abc|opq|sss
 c  auc|chc|ggg  abc|ccc|shg  gtc|lmn|trs  hyt|lki|ddd
```

I don't want to get an extra column like in this question [grep one pattern over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194714/grep-one-pattern-over-multiple-columns) , I want to subset the data.frame based on the pattern

Thanks

Comment: @RonakShah, sorry it was a error doing copy and paste

Comment: Try `df1 %>% filter_at(vars(V2:V5), any_vars(grepl("abc", .)))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, this method runs faster than the solutions posted. I was also thinking of subsetting first my data.frame, getting the index of rows matching the pattern on that subset of my data.frame and then using that index to subset the big data.frame. Although I don't know if that would be faster

Comment: If you really care about speed then it might make sense to get rid of the grep if possible. Are you always searching for an entire term? Or are you searching for parts of terms? For instance, are you always searching for "abc" or would you sometimes be searching for just "ab"? Also, do you receive the data in "abc|ccc|ggg" format or are you doing a process that puts it in that format? If you get the data that way it make sense, but there may be faster ways to handle things if you get the data in a different format.

Comment: @AdamSampson, my format is always like that, there are another 100 columns but I am interested in grep a pattern included into a pipe, sometimes is the first term but sometime not, definetely I would like to speed the process if I can rid of grep. Any help would be appreciated, my data.frame looks like this <https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfmv6npiiu8n6zv/big_df.txt?dl=0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
df1 %>% filter_at(vars(V2:V5), any_vars(grepl("abc", .)))
```

Should you want something faster than `grepl()`, use `stringi::stri_detect_fixed()`

```
big_df1 <- bind_rows(replicate(10e5, df1, simplify = FALSE))

mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grepl = big_df1 %>% 
    filter_at(
      vars(V2:V5), 
      any_vars(grepl("abc", .))),
  stringi = big_df1 %>% 
    filter_at(
      vars(V2:V5), 
      any_vars(stringi::stri_detect_fixed(., "abc"))),
  times = 5L
)
```

Which gives:

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#   grepl 2603.2713 2613.4157 2665.3730 2646.4757 2709.6653 2754.037     5
# stringi  823.3735  832.9813  888.5228  901.2059  911.8805  973.173     5
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sapply()` which applies `grep()` column-wise. The values have to be unlisted and sorted, so you get the rows.

```
df1[sort(unique(unlist(sapply(df1, function(x) grep('abc', x))))), ]

#   V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
# 1  a abc|ccc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg yyy|lmn|trs abc|ggt|hgy
# 2  b atc|cjc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg abc|lmn|trs abc|opq|sss
# 3  c auc|chc|ggg abc|ccc|shg gtc|lmn|trs hyt|lki|ddd
```

*Data*

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("abc|ccc|ggg", 
"aoc|cfc|ggg", "atc|cjc|ggg", "auc|chc|ggg"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("abc|ccc|shg", 
    "ttt|ccc|shg"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("abc|lmn|trs", "gtc|lmn|trs", "yyy|lmn|trs"
    ), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("abc|ggt|hgy", 
    "abc|opq|sss", "hyt|lki|ddd", "rmn|wde|tre"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `sapply` to loop over columns which would return a logical vector for each element indicating whether pattern "abc" is present or not and then filter out the rows which has at least one "abc"

```
cols <- c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")
df[rowSums(sapply(df[cols], function(x) grepl("abc", x))) > 0, ]

#   V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
#1   a abc|ccc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg yyy|lmn|trs abc|ggt|hgy
#2   b atc|cjc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg abc|lmn|trs abc|opq|sss
#3   c auc|chc|ggg abc|ccc|shg gtc|lmn|trs hyt|lki|ddd
```

---

Not really a `data.table` expert but following the same logic we can do

```
library(data.table)
dt[rowSums(dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("abc", x))]) > 0, ]


#   V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
#1:  a abc|ccc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg yyy|lmn|trs abc|ggt|hgy
#2:  b atc|cjc|ggg ttt|ccc|shg abc|lmn|trs abc|opq|sss
#3:  c auc|chc|ggg abc|ccc|shg gtc|lmn|trs hyt|lki|ddd
```

Comment: thanks, Could this example be translated to a data.table format? My real dataset is huge and speed on subsetting it is crucial

Comment: @user2380782 updated the answer with `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a some ways.

In the first one the `sapply` returns a logical matrix with one row per row of `df1` by using `grepl` for the indicated pattern.  Then use `rowSums` to find which rows have a TRUE.  Finally we subset by that.

In the second we paste together the indicated columns of `df1` and then run a `grepl` and finally subset by that.

The third is the same as the second but uses data.table.

The fourth uses `Reduce` working column by column.

```
# 1
df1[ rowSums(sapply(df1[-1], grepl, pattern = "abc")) > 0, ]

# 2
df1[grepl("abc", do.call("paste", c(df1[-1]))), ]

# 3
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt1[grepl("abc", do.call("paste", dt1[, -1]))]

# 4
df1[Reduce(function(x, y) x | grepl("abc", y), init = FALSE, df1), ]
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "V1  V2           V3           V4           V5
 a  abc|ccc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  yyy|lmn|trs  abc|ggt|hgy
 b  atc|cjc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  abc|lmn|trs  abc|opq|sss
 c  auc|chc|ggg  abc|ccc|shg  gtc|lmn|trs  hyt|lki|ddd
 d  aoc|cfc|ggg  ttt|ccc|shg  yyy|lmn|trs  rmn|wde|tre"
df1 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could this example be translated to a data.table format? My real dataset is huge and speed on subsetting it is crucial

Comment: Added as third solution.